# Wireless Clients unable to connect to internet

Tags: windows-server-2008, router, wifi, ip-address, dhcp-server

Our small office network consists of 2 windows 2008 servers, and 14 workstations (8 running windows 7 and 6 running windows xp) and 1 router(wired/wireless). The main server has DHCP, DNS, Active directory configured. Server 2 acts as a backup server with AD replicated and DNS.
DHCP has been disabled on the router so clients connecting wirelessly would have IP addresses issued by Server 1, for some reason most of our wireless clients can connect to the wireless network but cannot connect to the internet unless we assign static IP addresses. any suggestions as to what may be wrong?

Comment: Does your DHCP scope hand out a default gateway and external DNS or internal DNS with forwarders?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your DHCP server is assigning a valid default gateway, subnet mask, and/or name server(s).

If it is not this, then please provide a brief explanation of your ip addressing scheme. (E.g. are all your clients and servers on the same subnet, and using the same gateway?)

Comment: DHCP is definately assigning default gateway, subnet and name servers all configured properly. we are using a 172.16.x.x scheme with the router on .0.1 DNS servers .0.10 and .0.11 DHCP scope (.0.99 to .0.250). The router addr is default gateway

Comment: Try to isolate the problem by performing a few tests, E.g. can you ping a public IP address? If you can, then the problem may be with name resolution. Also, what error does your browser display when you try to visit a public website?

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved: we discovered a fault on the router, it kept resetting to default values and reactivating its dhcp and as such acting as a rogue dchp server.